# ggplot has a few errors with a faceted plot. Trying to coordinate y values with a faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, facet, facet-wrap

So I am trying to edit the y-values on a faceted ggplot because I am getting a couple inaccuracies on the plot when I knit. I am very new to R and R Markdown, so I can't quite figure out why, for example, the GDP PPP of the US has a lower bar than the other values when it has the highest dollar amount. There are also some discrepancies in the other values where the bars seem a lot higher when there is only about a $100-$500 difference in the values. Does anyone know what might be the issue? Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

OECD_IMF <- read.csv("OECD_IMF.csv")
attach(OECD_IMF)
detach(OECD_IMF)

OECD_IMFlong <- gather(OECD_IMF, key="measure", value="value", c("GDP_Nom_T" , "GDP_PPP" ,"Aid_Perc"))

variable_names <- list("GDP_Nom_T" = "GDP Per Capita 2018 (USD Thousands)" ,
  "GDP_PPP" = "GDP Purchasing Power Parity 2018 (USD Trillions)",
  "Aid_Perc" = "Average % of Gross National Income Given in Foreign Aid (2000-2016)")

variable_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(variable_names[value])}

ggplot(OECD_IMFlong, aes(x=Country, y=value, fill=Country))+
geom_bar(stat='identity')+ geom_text(aes(label=value), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=2.1)+ 
facet_wrap(~measure, scales="free_y", ncol=1, labeller= variable_labeller)+ 
labs(caption="Source: Official Development Assistance Database & IMF World Economic Outlook")+ ylab("Value")+ 
theme_grey() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot]

Comment: For PPP, if the values are in "T", R does not know what it is.. what is class(OECD_IMFlong$value)? I don't see the code you have actually produces this plot because i see geom_text(aes(label=value), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=2.1)

Comment: and ggplot(OECD_IMFlong, aes(x=Country, y=value, fill=Country))+ geom_bar(stat='identity'), which means "22.2T" and 67,063.. are in the same column, so you are actually plotting factors.. and not continuous values

Comment: Do you mind doing dput(OECD_IMFlong) and paste the output as part of your post? Your problem can be fixed once you keep a separate column for values and labels

Comment: structure(list(Country = structure(c(7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Canada", 
"France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    GDP_Nom = c(6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 
    4.3118e-05, 4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05, 6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 
    4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 4.3118e-05, 4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05, 
    6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 4.3118e-05, 
    4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05), measure = c("GDP_Nom_T",

Comment: "GDP_Nom_T", 
    "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", 
    "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", 
    "GDP_PPP", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", 
    "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc"), value = c("$67,063.00", 
    "$44,062.00", "$43,450.00", "$48,553.00", "$43,118.00", "$49,617.00", 
    "$34,575.00", "$20.54", "$2.78", "$4.97", "$1.71", "$2.86", 
    "$3.95", "$2.08", "0.1717", "0.0467", "0.2108", "0.2843", 
    "0.4963", "0.374", "0.1869")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I'm not sure where you see (OECD_IMFlong$value) in my code. I'm not sure how I could separate the columns for values and labels. When I go into the data with OECD_IMFlong, I see everything is in a separate column

Comment: The answer below should work for you? Try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

As @StupidWolf already pointed out, the problem is that your `value` column is a character and not a numeric vector. So you have to convert `value` to a numeric before plotting. To get both the values and labels right I added a new var `value1` which is the numeric given to `geom_bar` while `value` remains as a character and is given to geom_text to label the bars with nice $-labels. Try this

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

OECD_IMFlong <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Canada", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), GDP_Nom = c(6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 4.3118e-05, 4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05, 6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 4.3118e-05, 4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05, 6.7063e-05, 4.4062e-05, 4.345e-05, 4.845e-05, 4.3118e-05, 4.9617e-05, 3.4575e-05), measure = c("GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_Nom_T", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "GDP_PPP", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc", "Aid_Perc"), value = c("$67,063.00", "$44,062.00", "$43,450.00", "$48,553.00", "$43,118.00", "$49,617.00", "$34,575.00", "$20.54", "$2.78", "$4.97", "$1.71", "$2.86", "$3.95", "$2.08", "0.1717", "0.0467", "0.2108", "0.2843", "0.4963", "0.374", "0.1869")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")


variable_names <- list("GDP_Nom_T" = "GDP Per Capita 2018 (USD Thousands)" ,
                       "GDP_PPP" = "GDP Purchasing Power Parity 2018 (USD Trillions)",
                       "Aid_Perc" = "Average % of Gross National Income Given in Foreign Aid (2000-2016)")

variable_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  return(variable_names[value])}


OECD_IMFlong_tidy <- OECD_IMFlong %>% 
  mutate(value1 = str_replace_all(value, "(,|\\$)", "")) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = as.numeric(value1))


ggplot(OECD_IMFlong_tidy, aes(x=Country, y=value1, fill=Country))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=2.1)+ 
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales="free_y", ncol=1, labeller= variable_labeller)+ 
  labs(caption="Source: Official Development Assistance Database & IMF World Economic Outlook") + 
  theme_grey() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
#> Warning: The labeller API has been updated. Labellers taking `variable` and
#> `value` arguments are now deprecated. See labellers documentation.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: My pleasure. Could you mark the answer as accepted. Besides adding to my repuation the question will be removed from the list of questions still waiting for an answer.